# Call JavaScript from external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to create a horizontal parallax site. Everything is working nicely, when I click the menu the slides move swiftly to the horizontal direction and the corresponding slide is displayed.

I have an external HTML page, that has the same structure as the main site and the problem is that when I click this page's menu, it goes to the site but lands on the first slide.

I want a script so that when I click on this external HTML page link, the page should land on the site, but then it should slide to the corresponding slide.

Main menu link looks like this:

```
<a onclick="HORIZONTAL.ANIM.instance.move(3);" id="sec4" href="javascript:void(0);">About Us</a>
```

I want to click on About Us link on external page and then it should land on the main site and then the above script should run and slide should move.

Comment: did you try passing `ID` of your slide in querystring? and write  logic in external page to show that slide

Comment: you have to send the section id to the url as querystring or hash (ex: http://example.com/slides/#/1

Comment: had you used hashes and hashchange event handling to manage the animations you wouldn't have the problem. Then different parts of page are bookmarkable

Comment: @irvgk @Ammaroff  Actually my page doesn't have a `ID of a slide` kind of thing. It is divided into %. what i called slide is the section of the same page which which shows when the link is clicked.  The number 3 in the code `onclick="HORIZONTAL.ANIM.instance.move(3);"` means, it will slide 300% in the horizontal/right direction and the content on that position will be shown.

Comment: `it should land on the main site and then the above script should run` You can't run your script in some external page.. If that page supports hashtags you can directly do http://getbootstrap.com/components/#wells will work

If you have access to other site you can write your logic based on url change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First refer user to new page ( for example http://newpage.com" )with slide id in hash.

```
<a href="http:/newpage.com#3">About Us</a>
```

in that new page create a script after page loads that slides to specified slide passed.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var id = window.location.hash.substr(1);//get id from url after hash
    HORIZONTAL.ANIM.instance.move(id);
    };
```

Comment: It did it. I was looking for the same code. thanks. Looks it was quite easy, I am quite new and naive to the JQuery though. thanks mate.